# Gantt View and Javascript Events

Tags: javascript, events, gantt-view

I'm displaying a Gantt view in a page in like this:

```
  <Module Name="DefaultBlank" Url="" Path="">
    <File Path="EmployeeWorkspacePages\default.aspx"  Url="default.aspx" >
       <View WebPartZoneID="WebPartZone3" List="Lists/OvedKlitaPlan" Name="GanttView"
             BaseViewID="13"  Type="GANTT">
       </View>
    </File>
  </Module>
```

The Gantt view is shows on the page, but I do have some problems...

1) How can I catch a javascript event after I changes one of the fields in the left pane? (I need this to refresh another webpart after changes updated)

2) Is there a way to make some columns read only in the left pane?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Please reopen this item as I have similar requests.  I'm doing custom formatting for a Sharepoint Gantt view and when items are updated or the zoom functions are used my formatting is lost.  I'd like to find out what event is triggered on those changes and see if I can get them to re-trigger my formatting functions. I'd like to make some of the columns on the left side read only as well. Thank you